# how to test an angularjs app on node webkit

Tags: angularjs, node-webkit

What are my options for testing if I want to run an angularjs app in node-webkit?

I had a look at the nw docs for testing and they did not really make sense to me https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/How-to-run-node-webkit%27s-test-cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html) and [jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/) for testing my node-webkit applications. There is a [karma-node-webkit launcher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-nodewebkit-launcher) which makes it possible to run those tests.

Answer (score 1):

This module was very useful for me in testing angular with nodewebkit - [nwjs test runner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nwjs-test-runner)

Answer (score 0):

Your link describes the tests for node-webkit itself.

There's a different wiki page for testing your own app: [Testing framework for your application running on node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/chromedriver)